# Apscheduler script file stops silently - no error

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have a `scheduler_project.py` script file.

**code:**

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

def func_1():
   # updating file-1

def func_2():
   # updating file-2

scheduler.add_job(func_1, 'cron', hour='10-23' , minute='0-58', second=20)
scheduler.add_job(func_2, 'cron', hour='1')

scheduler.start()
```

When I run, (on Windows machine)

```
E:\> python scheduler_project.py 
E:\>                            # there is no error
```

In Log: (I have added `logging` in above code at debug level)

> It says, job is added and starts in (some x seconds), but it is not
>   starting.

In task manager, the command prompt process display for a second and disappear.

And my files are also not getting updated, which is obvious.

What's happening? What is the right way to execute this scheduler script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduler was created to run with other code - so after starting scheduler you can run other code.

If you don't have any other job then you have to use some loop to run it all time.

In [documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html) you can see link to examples on GitHub and [one of example](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/examples/schedulers/background.py) uses

```
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: If I increase sleep time to very large number, do that effect my script or is there any side effects?

Comment: it runs in separated thread - doc [BackgroundScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/schedulers/background.html#apscheduler.schedulers.background.BackgroundScheduler) - so sleep can be bigger and it should work the same way.